# why cannot I print in jupyter lab using ipywidgets class?

Tags: python, vuetify.js, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I use the ipyvuetify librairy to create dashboard in a Jupyter environment. The lib works super nicely but I'm struggling with Jupyterlab and voila that seems to have the same behavior with respect to this problem:

let's assume I want to create a widget that when clicked print a message :

```py
import ipyvuetify as v 

class Test(v.Btn):
    
    def __init__(self, msg):
        
        self.msg = msg
        
        super().__init__(children=['click'])
        
        self.on_event('click', self._on_click)
        
    def _on_click(self, widget, event, data):
        
        print(self.msg)
        
        return
    
btn = Test(toto)
btn
```

If I run this code from Jupyter Notebook, everything works fine, the `msg` is printed after the `btn` cell output. If I do the same in Jupyterlab, the print statement ends up in the log.

now if run :

```py
btn._on_click(None, None, None)
```

the `msg` is printed in both Jupyterlab and Jupyter Notebook.

Can someone explain me why there is a behaviour difference and maybe how to make sure that my print statement ends up in the main workflow and not in the log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, JupyterLab has implemented a different mechanism than Jupyter Notebook to capture output, via the **Output widget** of ipywidget:

```py
import ipyvuetify as v
import ipywidgets as w

class Test(v.Btn):
    output = w.Output()
    def __init__(self, msg):
        
        self.msg = msg
        
        super().__init__(children=['click'])
        
        self.on_event('click', self._on_click)
        
    @output.capture()
    def _on_click(self, widget, event, data):
        
        print(self.msg)
        
        return

    def _ipython_display_(self):
        display(super(),self.output)

    
btn = Test('toto')
btn
```

[Ipywidget documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html#Debugging-errors-in-callbacks-with-the-output-widget): the output from `_on_click` is directed to `output` by using either a context manager `with self.output:` over `print()`, or the `capture` decorator to capture all the output produced by the `_on_click` function (example above).

Some explanation in https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3151#issuecomment-339476572:

> We kludged a backwards-compatibility workaround in the classic notebook, but we didn't in jupyterlab. Part of the reason is that it is much harder to write kludgy workarounds in jlab :).
>
> Essentially, the technical issue is that a widget comm message from
> the browser to the client would need to set the output callback to
> append output to the current output area - but IIRC it's hard from a
> mime renderer to get a handle on the output area that contains it.